# Object implementing the Parcelable interface containing a List throws a NullPointerException

Tags: android, parcelable

I am trying to make an object containing a `List` of objects parcelable using the `Parcelable` interface. I am not able to read the `Parcel` object back in.

Can anyone point me in the right direction? What am I missing here?

`MyParcelable` object:

```
public class MyParcelable implements Parcelable {

    private int myInt = 0;
    private List<MyListClass> arrList;

    public List<MyListClass> getArrList() {
        return arrList;
    }

    public void setArrList(List<MyListClass> arrList) {
        this.arrList = arrList;
    }

    public int getMyInt() {
        return myInt;
    }

    public void setMyInt(int myInt) {
        this.myInt = myInt;
    }

    MyParcelable() {
        // initialization
        arrList = new ArrayList<MyListClass>();
    }

    public MyParcelable(Parcel in) {
        myInt = in.readInt();
        in.readTypedList(arrList, MyListClass.CREATOR);
    }

    @Override
    public int describeContents() {
        return 0;
    }

    @Override
    public void writeToParcel(Parcel outParcel, int flags) {
        outParcel.writeInt(myInt);
        outParcel.writeTypedList(arrList);
    }

    public static final Parcelable.Creator<MyParcelable> CREATOR =
            new Parcelable.Creator<MyParcelable>() {

        @Override
        public MyParcelable createFromParcel(Parcel in) {
            return new MyParcelable(in);
        }

        @Override
        public MyParcelable[] newArray(int size) {
            return new MyParcelable[size];
        }
    };
}
```

`MyListClass` object:

```
  public class MyListClass implements Parcelable{

    private int test;

    public MyListClass()
    {}

    public MyListClass(Parcel read){
        test = read.readInt();
    }

    public int getTest() {
        return test;
    }

    public void setTest(int test) {
        this.test = test;
    }

    public static final Parcelable.Creator<MyListClass> CREATOR = 
        new Parcelable.Creator<MyListClass>() {

            @Override
            public MyListClass createFromParcel(Parcel source) {
                return new MyListClass(source);
            }

            @Override
            public MyListClass[] newArray(int size) {
                return new MyListClass[size];
            }
        };

    @Override
    public int describeContents() {
        return 0;
    }

    @Override
    public void writeToParcel(Parcel arg0, int arg1) {
        arg0.writeInt(test);
    }
}
```

Comment: why is your MyListClass **not** Parcelable.

Comment: @Sam Quest I am getting problem in write and read List<MyListClass>.

Comment: to my understanding, when parceling takes place it has to be broken down in to primitive datatypes (int, string...) in you case if MyListClass is not parcelable this can be a problem, you have implemented parcelable for the list of objects, now the objects must also has to be serialzed one by one.

Comment: But, I have and idea that we can also parcel the List directly by using writeTypedList().

Comment: how will android know the method name **getTest()** and **setTest()** on its own.

Comment: on a side note if your data is this complex, you can simple pass some ids and query it on the other side. (applies if you have some db)

Comment: I have no idea about how to use Parcelable, it will be fine if you provide some solution that how can I overcome this problem.

Comment: @SamQuest let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/2144/discussion-between-suri-sahani-and-sam-quest)

Comment: tried chat. you weren't there when i came. in short you have to implement parcelable to both the classes. MyParcelable and the MyListClass. then it will work as desired.

Comment: Ok Thanks. I will try and let you know there after.

Comment: @SamQuest Please post that as an answer. You are spot on. ;)

Answer (score 16, accepted):

The problem is that when the creator of your `MyParcelable` object calls the private constructor that takes the `Parcel` from which you reconstruct the object, the `ArrayList` is still uninitialized thus `null`.

Now the method call `readTypedList()` tries to write the `Parcel`s content to the `ArrayList` you've specified which throws a `NullPointerEception` since it isn't initialized yet.

The solution is to initialize the `ArrayList` before calling that method.

```java
public MyParcelable(Parcel in) {
    myInt = in.readInt();
    arrList = new ArrayList<MyListClass>();
    in.readTypedList(arrList, MyListClass.CREATOR);
}
```

Comment: "The problem is that when the creator of your MyParcelable object calls the private constructor that takes the Parcel from which you reconstruct the object, the ArrayList is still uninitialized thus null." completely forgot about this part, gj.

Answer (score 1):

`in.readTypedList(arrList, MyListClass.CREATOR);`

arrList at this point has not been initialised when you call `return new MyParcelable(in);`